# Rubocop autocorrect for FrozenStringLiteralComment not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have a Rails 6 project and am trying to use RuboCop's `auto-correct` option to fix the many `Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment` errors (mostly in generated files).

No matter how many times I run `bundle exec rubocop --auto-correct --only Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment` from the project root, Rubocop will only report the errors, but not auto-correct them:

`app/models/product.rb:1:1: C: Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment: Missing frozen string literal comment.`

From running with the `--show-cops` option I can see that this cop 'Supports --auto-correct,' so am not sure what's wrong.

My `.rubocop.yml` file has only one config setting: `require: rubocop-rails`.

I've also run `bundle exec rubocop -a` and it has corrected other errors in config and similar files (single-quoting, mostly).

Any idea why auto-correct won't work in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a breaking change introduced in the version 0.87 (see the [issue](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/8156)).

Quoting from there:

> rubocop -a does all autocorrections, including unsafe ones. One has to add --safe-auto-correct to exclude unsafe ones.

You should use the `-A` flag now to safe and/or unsafe autocorrect your files:

> rubocop -a / --autocorrect no longer run unsafe corrections; rubocop -A / --autocorrect-all run both safe and unsafe corrections. Options --safe-autocorrect is deprecated

It should work for you as:

```
bundle exec rubocop -A --only Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment
```